# Display all rows from table but first where id=x - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL.
I wanted to know that if its possible to show all the rows from the table but first where id='some value'. ie.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id='some value'
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that. But I guess that's not the answer you were looking for. Please read [ask].

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a set of queries, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= 5 UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != 5;
```

Or if you need something like this example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id >= 5;
```

Comment: Marcos David Huaranga Ortega, Thanks you very much!